# How to fix bad sector on NAND Flash Memory

Tags: rom-flashing, samsung-nexus-s, external-sd, reformat

A week ago, I flashed my Nexus S 4g with a custom kernel (Matrix) and ROM (CWM9). On reboot, my NS4G always bootloops, stuck on bootloader loading screen, and never gets to the Android System. It had the same result when I tried to flash it back to a stock ROM.

I removed the battery, put it again and tried to boot into recovery to use adb to check my SD card content with parted (I think there was a problem on partition). In parted I can reformat it using adb or recovery, but its content couldn't be changed. I think there was a problem with NAND flash.

Is there any way that I could Reformat NAND flash to fresh state?

Comment: Can you try restoring stock firmware & see if the problem persists? If so, turn the phone in for warranty. If not, it's an issue with the ROM.

Comment: since I dont bought it on my country, they wouldn't check/fix my phone. :(

no, I can't restoring stock firmware... :(

Comment: Stock firmware is available from Google: https://developers.google.com/android/nexus/images

Comment: also, make sure you wipe the cache and system between flashing ROMS.

Comment: it's been a while. Since I dont know what happen here, I sold it to a friend. Case Closed... :)